# Interpreting partial eta squared and reporting it apa style

Tags: effect-size

How do you interpret and report partial eta-squared in a two-way anova?
I have run a two-way anova to inspect whether gender and level of education interact to have an effect on positive affect.
Together, they do.
Partial eta-squared  = 0.67.
What does this mean, and how would I report it apa-style, along with the F Statistic, degrees of freedom, sample size and p value?
Thank you.